# Digitar valores decimais no teclado do computador e ter a resposta na tela do computador usando arduino

Tags: arduino

Quero ter o arduino conectado em meu computador e através do teclado do computador digitar dois valores com casas cecimais, como por exemplo 10,5 e 12,7 e que o arduino efetue a soma e apresente o resultado na tela.Como faço isso?

Comment: Fábio, você já tentou alguma coisa? Qual a dificuldade exatamente está tendo? Para evitar que sua pergunta seja sinalizada como muito ampla, já que pedir código pode gerar uma dezena ou mais de respostas possíveis, é melhor relatar exatamente a dificuldade.